# htaccess RewriteCond, will it affect all the rules below it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess that looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^irefox+
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html?(.*)$ /handler.php?a=%{QUERY_STRING}&b=$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^irefox+
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html?(.*)$ /handler.php?a=%{QUERY_STRING}&b=$2&c=firefox

RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/$ /index.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Will the RewriteCond affect only the first rule below it, or will it affect the last 2 also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the RewriteCond affect only the first rule below it, or will it affect the last 2 also?

`RewriteCond` only affects the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^irefox+
```

will not have any affect on

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/$ /index.php?tag=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

If you want those conditions to also be applied, then repeat them above the rules.